# Yii Cgridview Erases JS On Refresh

Tags: yii

I'm using bootstrap and [Bootstrap Editable extension](http://vitalets.github.com/bootstrap-editable/) in my GridView to edit data fast. It's awesome, but when I somehow refresh my gridview with AJAX (e.g. apply some fiter or delete a row) it dissapears from the page and if I want to edit-in-place again I have to refresh page manually (F5). This is how I apply editable plugin in my views/admin.php file:

```
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(
    Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(
        Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.editable.assets.js').'/bootstrap-editable.min.js'
    ),
    CClientScript::POS_HEAD
); 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(
    Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(
        Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.editable.assets.css').'/bootstrap-editable.css'
    ),
    CClientScript::POS_HEAD
); 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('editable', '$(".editable").editable();', CClientScript::POS_END); 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCss('popover', '.popover{width: 600px !important;} .editable-popover{width: auto !important;}', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

It's kind of messy, but I'm just trying to get it working.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I have a feeling it is something to do with jQuery live (assuming this a jQuery extension), where the script is only recognizing DOM elements on the first load. Check out http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Yep, also thought of that, this is how Editable popover binded in js:  http://pastie.org/5138809 and i need to change this 'click' to something that will do 'live' instead of just 'bind'. But I don't know how :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail

ie.

> 'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'function() { $(".editable").editable(); }'

Comment: Thanks! Not the best implementation, though, but it works and for now - it is the most important.